# In Google Apps Script Is there a way to reorder sheets/tabs in standalone projects?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a Google Apps Script that pulls API data from a remote source and then writes it to various tabs in a Google Sheets spreadsheet. The Apps Script project is not bound to the spreadsheet, so we use this code to get the specific spreadsheet.

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId)
```

I would like to ensure that all of the tabs in this spreadsheet are in the proper left to right order. Is there a way to do this in a standalone GAS project?

I know that this function [moveActiveSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveactivesheetpos) can move the active sheet, but since this is a standalone project, I don't believe that I can get the active sheet since I'm not loading the initial sheet with:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

Is that correct? Is there some way to use moveActiveSheet in a standalone GAS project?

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do it with Sheets API bacthUpdate for sheets. The Sheet Properties contains the index: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm somewhat new to coding, so there might be a simpler way to do this. but I just ran this and it worked on this [sample sheet i created for this question](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-4cztjNX7QlFCFFDoxk5PYm36Tx37jtlAiMbH6w2ztE/edit#gid=0).

```
function sheetOrder() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1-4cztjNX7QlFCFFDoxk5PYm36Tx37jtlAiMbH6w2ztE');
  var sheetnames = new Array();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(function (each) { sheetnames.push(each.getName()) });
  sheetnames.sort();
  for (let i = 0; i < sheetnames.length; i++) {
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(sheetnames[i]));
    ss.moveActiveSheet(i + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this answers my question and shows me how to use moveActiveSheet in standalone projects.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to MattKing's already good answer.

If your sheet tabs are named as dates (e.g. **December 2018**, **January 2019**, **March 2018**) and want to sort the tabs based on the date, add this function. (This might come in handy for you on some spreadsheets)

```
function dateCompare(a, b) {
  var dateA = new Date(a);
  var dateB = new Date(b);
  if (dateA.getTime() < dateB.getTime())
    return -1;
  else if (dateA.getTime() > dateB.getTime())
    return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

And pass it to the `sort` function.

```
sheetnames.sort(dateCompare);
```

#### Default Sort:

[image: normal]

#### Custom Date Sort:

[image: custom]

Comment: Thanks!  makes total sense and super likely that this is the use case!  I'm still learning....

Comment: No problem @MattKing, your answer already actually works but since OP wasn't able to give a sample value of the sheet names, them being dates is a possibility so instead of modifying your answer, I provided an option in which OP would just copy paste this one and should sort the tabs just in case the names are in date.